# Importing only diff of mysql schema from server A to B

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I do have a DEV mysql server where I change the table design of several tables.

We also do have a second DEV mysql server where other team members are changing the design as well.

My question is: Is there a way to simply import the difference of the schema of each table from one to another server in order to keep them synched?
Data is not relevant. Just the schema. Having only one DEV server is unfortunatley not an option.

Thanks for any hints.
Alex

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly use mysqldump to then import in the Prod DB.

mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p --no-data dbname1>file1
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p --no-data dbname2>file2

or use

schemasync [options]

Comment: Please provide at least some examples or a link